# How to create new delimiters: dashed \langle and \rangle?

Tags: brackets, delimiters

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,lipsum}

\begin{document}

$\langle 1,2,a,b\rangle$

\end{document}
```

**Question: How to create variants of `\langle` and `\rangle` in which the lines are dashed? Also, I hope that the size of the new symbols change to match the font size and they can be used with `\left` and `\right` commands.**

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: I understand Metafont can be used to create font files, and \DeclareMathSymbol with \mathopen and \mathclose can be used with \left and \right.  Personally, I would fake it with a savebox and TikZ.

Comment: @Kuttens Which engine are you using? LuaTeX?

Comment: @Marcel Krüger Xelatex. But it seems that it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Kuttens At least if you want to use the new delimiters with \left and \right, I am pretty sure you need to create a font or use LuaTeX.

Comment: @Marcel Krüger I use XeLatex, and so could you show how to create them?

Comment: @Kuttens No, you would have to create a font and I do not have a lot of experience in this area. I can only recommend using John Kormylo's answer instead to fake it, that is significantly less work.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of faking it with Tikz...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle x \tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{\node[anchor=base, inner sep=1pt] (A) {$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$};
  \draw[dashed] (A.south west) -- ($(A.west)+(-.5em,0)$) -- (A.north west);
  \draw[dashed] (A.south east) -- ($(A.east)+(0.5em,0)$) -- (A.north east);
  \path (current bounding box.west)++(-2pt,0) (current bounding box.east)++(2pt,0);}
$

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Could u define langle and range seperately?

Comment: Not with this approach.  They are drawn around the text (node).  OTOH, the first \draw does the \langle and the second does the \rangle.

Comment: But then the symbols won't change the size with `\left` or `\right`.

Comment: They change size based on what is inside the node.  Different protocol but same results.

Comment: Because of frequent uses of them, there are some differences for the results.

Comment: By the way, how do you read your surname?

Comment: I pronounce it "core mellow" but have been told that it should be pronouced "core me low" (while rolling the r).  Not that it matters.

Comment: Well, close to what I thought.